# F# treating operators as functions

Tags: f#, functional-programming

In F#, is there a way to treat an operator as a function? In context, I'd like to partially apply operators (both infix and prefix), but the compiler only seems happy to partially apply functions.

Example:
Instead of being able to write `List.map (2 **) [0..7];;` I have to define my own function `pow x y` (and then another function `let swap f x y = f y x;;` because the compiler won't let me partially apply `|>` either, as in `List.map (|> pow 2) [0..7];;`.) In the end, my code needs to be `List.map (swap pow 2) [0..7];;` to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would just do:

```
[0..7] |> List.map (fun n -> pown n 2)
```

Or, if 2 is the base:

```
[0..7] |> List.map (pown 2)
```

This works too:

```
[0.0..7.0] |> List.map (( ** ) 2.0)
```

Comment: The lambda works, and if rewritten like this then I'm not forced to go searching for an efficient algorithm of [insert_operator_name_here].
[0.0..7.0] |> List.map (fun y -> 2.0 ** y);;

Comment: The other option still forces me to define ** as a function though.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. After squinting at your 3rd example I discovered it's actually the whitespace that's been catching me out and I can, in fact, invoke List.map (( |> ) 2.0 ( ** )) [0.0..7.0];;

Comment: @Jono - While you can certainly write `(( |> ) 2.0 ( ** ))` as an argument of `List.map`, I honestly think that this is a really bad idea. It has _exactly_ the same number of characters as `(fun a -> a ** 2.0)` and it takes _much_ longer to decipher what is actually going on. The thrid example from Daniel is pretty common, so I think that's fine, but anything beyond that is often too complicated. (Although this is just my personal preference and anybody can disagree with it.)

Comment: @Tomas, totally agree; reading my code even gives me a headache, but I'm just playing around here. Pipe-right was presumably added to make F# easier to read and I am wilfully abusing it. Final thought: is the lambda any less efficient for its gain in readability?

Comment: @Jono - That's fine then :-) writing code without explicit lambdas is definitely an interesting and fun exercise (I occasionaly do that too, but I wouldn't admit that publicly!) I don't think there is any notable difference in te performance - if yes, then I'd expect `fun` to be faster (but I didn't test it).

Comment: `(( |> ) 2.0 ( ** ))` can be made look as `( 2.0 |> ( ** ))`

Answer (score 3):

There are no 'operator sections' a la Haskell; use a lambda to partially apply operators, e.g.

```
(fun x -> x - 10)
```

You can partially apply the first argument if you make an infix operator be prefix by surrounding it in parens, e.g.

```
(fun x -> 10.0 / x)
```

and

```
((/) 10.0)
```

mean the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, Brian. Any ideas why (/) doesn't need spaces, but ( ** ) does, even though both operators are infix?

Comment: @Jono - becaus `(*` opens a comment and `*)` closes a comment. So `(**)` is just whitespace.